# Why activity_main.xml screen just white?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I opening new project and same thing. MainActivity.java normally working, but activity_main.xml not normal. I can't see buttons or text or images. I can put them there but i cant see. When i run application, buttons, text, images are stay random places. What can i do for fix this?

Comment: Please add code for activity and xml

Comment: Just starter codes noting else. Not different things.

Comment: @Berkan really, add code please.

Answer (score 0):

try rebuilding your app.

if the problem does not solve then make sure you have installed sdk files properly. for eg. if your app targetSdkVersion=27 then open sdk manager and install necessary image files

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Just changed theme on activity_main.xml